# Sorting expressions on SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, server-side-rendering

I've created a table on Visual studio (SSRS) that has 1 parent group and 2 child groups with drilldown, one of the child groups is a union of 2 columns from the sql script , Below is the expression used on that one:

```
    =IIF(Count(Fields!Terminal_ID.Value)>1 ,
Fields!Tier_1_Customer.Value & " (" &  Count(Fields!Terminal_ID.Value) & " POS terminals)",
Fields!Tier_1_Customer.Value & " (" &  Count(Fields!Terminal_ID.Value) & " POS terminal)")
```

The result of that will be something like:

```
 Store # 4 ( 1 device)
 Store # 3 ( 2 devices)
 Store # 8 ( 9 devices)
```

What I cannot figure out how to do is how to apply a sort so it can display the data from z to a as below:

```
Store # 8 ( 9 devices)
Store # 3 ( 2 devices)
Store # 4 ( 1 device)
```

I've applied different sorting options to the column but it does not work , any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go in to the child group properties. In the sort tab, use this expression:

```
=Count(Fields!Terminal_ID.Value)
```

Set it to descending (Z-A). This will sort the details of this group by this value.